# I'm trying to connect my databse on java, what might be the cause of error?

Tags: java, sqlite

What I want is to get data from my database which I saved on my workspace folder, I also installed the latest sqlite-jdbc jar...

I followed the tuts here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm
here is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class sqliteConnection {

    Connection conn = null;

    public static Connection dbConnector(){
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:TR.sqlite","","");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Successful");
            Statement stmt = null;

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM admin_tbl;");
            while ( rs.next() ) {
                int id = rs.getInt("admin_id");
                String  user = rs.getString("username");
                String  pass = rs.getString("password");
                System.out.println( "ID = " + id );
                System.out.println( "NAME = " + user );
                System.out.println( "ADDRESS = " + pass );
                System.out.println();
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            return conn;
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

First i get the result of "Connection Successful" then
I get this error...

```
 java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: admin_tbl)
```

Comment: no such table. That usually means there is 'no such table'. Check your db to verify the actual name of the table.

Comment: whats your database schema.? it seems you dont have a table named `admin_tbl`

Comment: tnx for the fast response and yes i did check and recreate the database for consistency and still gets the error... and i also updated the file on my workspace and make sure there is a data inputted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to give the path of your database file. Presently the driver manager is not able to find the database in which you table is present.

Try like this:

```
String path=this.getClass().getResource("somedatabase.db").getPath();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+path);
```

where path of the path of the database file in your system.

Comment: some static error came.. however i try to put the full path just like this.. 
     jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\johnguild\\workspace\\teacherRecords\\src\\teacherRecords\\TR.sqlite

it worked, but will this be fine if i install the finished application to diff pc..??

Comment: I recently got what i wanted.. thanks to your answer.
i input this code.. String path=sqliteConnection.class.getResource("TR.db").getPath();
then changed my conn code to... Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+path,"","");
i make your answer as the answer of my question.. once again tnx